# Le placement d'un adverbe avant le verbe

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

Je suis en train de lire "Le dérèglement du monde" par Amin Maalouf. Je le tiens à haut égard comme écrivain puisqu'il est un des immortels de l’Académie française.

J'ai constaté plusieurs fois au cours de la lecture de ce livre-là qu'il place l'adverbe avant le verbe. Par exemple, au début du chapitre 4 se trouve cette phrase:

> Pourtant, elle **aussi** se trouve aujourd'hui, à sa manière, dans une impasse historique qui affecte ses comportements et contribue au dérèglement du monde.

J'ai appris qu'une telle construction est contre les règles de grammaire du français. Peut-on m'expliquer pourquoi cette construction est bonne et dans quelles autres circonstances elle   (ou autres constructions similaires) est/sont acceptable(s) ?

Comment: Juste une précision : la tournure n'est pas propre à l'auteur, ni même associée au seul style littéraire. (Mais bien sûr, donner une référence précise est toujours utile, ce n'est pas pour contester son bien-fondé, simple remarque)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ici, l'adverbe est attaché au pronom sujet *elle*, pas au verbe.

```
Pourtant, elle aussi se trouve aujourd'hui, à sa manière, dans une impasse …
--------  ---------- --------- -----------  ------------  ------------------
   CC 1      sujet     verbe       CC 2          CC 3            CC 4
```

(CC = complément circonstanciel)

L'adverbe *aussi* qualifie *elle* : il signifie qu'elle n'est pas la seule entité pour laquelle l'affirmation est vraie, que la phrase peut aussi s'appliquer à d'autres entités qui ont été mentionnées auparavant.

C'est exactement la même construction que, par exemple, dans

> — J'ai faim.
>   — Moi aussi.

L'adverbe pourrait aussi être placé après le verbe, mais cela changerait le sens puisque l'adverbe qualifierait alors la phrase dans son ensemble.

```
Pourtant, elle se trouve aussi aujourd'hui, à sa manière, dans une impasse …
--------  ---- --------- ----- -----------  ------------  ------------------
   CC 1  sujet   verbe   CC 2     CC 3           CC 4            CC 5
```

Dans cette phrase modifiée, *aussi* qualifie la situation dans laquelle elle se trouve. Il se peut que d'autres entités déjà mentionnées soient dans la même situation (comme dans la phrase originale), ou que l'entité désignée par *elle* soit dans cette situation en plus d'autres situations déjà mentionnées.

Comment: Cela me paraît parfaitement sensible et compréhensible. Je n'avais pas pensé aux deux nuances de sens que la deuxième construction pourrait donner, ni à la parallèle de "moi aussi". Merci beaucoup !